# R: Gsub to conditionally remove spaces

Tags: r, text, gsub, spacing

For this question I have the following example which is a matrix with two character strings as rows:

```
mylist <- rbind("1  Henry Buchanon  45  60  70", "2  Julie  Tiscani  80  50  70")
```

I want this data in a table, so the most straight forward way would be to do:

```
mytable <- read.table(textConnection(mylist))
```

which produces the following table with one problem (for me) -- The first name and last name are in two separate columns (V2 and V3). I'd prefer something like the second table where the first and last name are in the same column (V2).

```
+------------------------------+
|   V1    V2       V3 V4 V5 V6 |
+------------------------------+
| 1  1 Henry Buchanon 45 60 70 |
| 2  2 Julie  Tiscani 80 50 70 |
+------------------------------+

+------------------------------+
|   V1             V2 V3 V4 V5 |
+------------------------------+
| 1  1 HenryBuchanon 45 60 70  |
| 2  2  JulieTiscani 80 50 70  |
+------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to omit only the space between the first and last name (e.g. between "Henry" and "Buchanon" and to keep the other spaces unaltered? The following code presents two problems: 1) The code deletes the letters of the search condition and 2) It only works for single-spacing.

```
gsub("([A-z])[[:space:]]([A-z])", "", mylist)

+--------------------------------------+
| [1,] "1  Henruchanon  45  60  70"    |
+--------------------------------------+
| [2,] "2  Julie  Tiscani  80  50  70" |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why not just `mytable$Name <- paste(mytable$V2,mytable$V3)`

Comment: Try `gsub("(?<=[A-z])[[:space:]]+(?=[A-z])", "", mylist,perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to create quotes to separate the first name/last name from the rest and then use `read.table`.  This will avoid the first and last names without spaces between them.

```
m1 <- gsub('(?<=\\d\\s)\\s*(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])\\s*(?=\\s\\d)',
                         "'", mylist, perl=TRUE)
read.table(text=m1, sep='', header=FALSE)
#  V1             V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1 Henry Buchanon 45 60 70
#2  2 Julie  Tiscani 80 50 70
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your example data a simple `‘paste’`will do it:

```
mytable$V1 <- paste(mytable$V2,mytable$V3); mytable <- mytable[,-c(2:3)]
mytable
> mytable
              V1 V4 V5 V6
1 Henry Buchanon 45 60 70
2  Julie Tiscani 80 50 70
```